# Fetch rows from 4 table in MySQL with heavy database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have activity, contact, user, deleted_contact table in my database.

- activity table has 5 million rows
- contact table has 5 million rows
- user table has 5000 rows
- delete_contact table has 850000 rows

Now my problem is that when I am trying to **fetch only 10 rows** by **joining all tables**, mysql takes too much load and sometime my app totally stops working.

I am applying left joining. Please suggest me best way to take only 10 rows from above four tables.

I have following query:-

```
SELECT activity.id,
       activity.ipaddress,
       deleted_contact.name,
       activity.city,
       activity.country,
       activity.state,
       activity.user_agent,
       activity.browser_name,
       activity.os_platform,
       activity.details AS details,
       activity.file_name AS filename,
       activity.created_at AS Date,
       activity.model_id,
       activity.user_id,
       activity.contact_id,
       activity.type,
       activity.city,
       activity.state,
       activity.country,
       contact.name AS Contact,
       email.subject AS emailsubject,
       email.opened,
       email.schedule_date,
       email.schedule_timezone,
FROM activity
LEFT JOIN contact ON activity.contact_id = contact.id
LEFT JOIN email ON activity.model_id = email.id
LEFT JOIN user ON activity.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN deleted_contact ON deleted_contact.contact_id = activity.contact_id
WHERE activity.user_id IN (2,
                           56,
                           78,
                           93,
                           105,
                           2004,
                           345,
                           450,
                           321,
                           456)
GROUP BY activity.id,
         email.id
ORDER BY activity.id DESC LIMIT 0,
                                10
```

Comment: Please add the query and some more information about the table structure like what indexes are in place etc.

Comment: How long does it take If you run the query in mysql(as opposed to in the app)

Comment: In my activity table I have indexs on user_id not unique,model_id not unique,contact_id no unique,notification no unique and on created_at not unique.

Comment: Are your id's in all tables primary keys?

Comment: yes I have primary key on id in each and every table. Jan-zeiseweis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found its answer. Actually when I performed Explain query in phpMyAdmin it was showing me that it is creating Temporary table because from activity table it has 26000 rows from those users and I am applying group by at the end of my query. So I removed group by it gave me very fast result with only 0.26 sec only.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your database and I can't prove my code but the idea is select this 10 rows with a subselect, before join all tables. This should be work faster than otherwise.

```
SELECT act.id,
       act.ipaddress,
       deleted_contact.name,
       act.city,
       act.country,
       act.state,
       act.user_agent,
       act.browser_name,
       act.os_platform,
       act.details AS details,
       act.file_name AS filename,
       act.created_at AS Date,
       act.model_id,
       act.user_id,
       act.contact_id,
       act.type,
       act.city,
       act.state,
       act.country,
       contact.name AS Contact,
       email.subject AS emailsubject,
       email.opened,
       email.schedule_date,
       email.schedule_timezone,
FROM 
  (SELECT activity.id,
       activity.ipaddress,
       activity.city,
       activity.country,
       activity.state,
       activity.user_agent,
       activity.browser_name,
       activity.os_platform,
       activity.details AS details,
       activity.file_name AS filename,
       activity.created_at AS Date,
       activity.model_id,
       activity.user_id,
       activity.contact_id,
       activity.type,
       activity.city,
       activity.state,
       activity.country
       FROM activity WHERE activity.user_id IN (2,56,78,93,105,2004,345,450,321,456) AS act)
LEFT JOIN contact ON act.contact_id = contact.id
LEFT JOIN email ON act.model_id = email.id
LEFT JOIN user ON act.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN deleted_contact ON deleted_contact.contact_id = act.contact_id
GROUP BY act.id,
         email.id
ORDER BY act.id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Actually I tried your query directly in my live server's phpmyadmin with "Explain" keyword so I found that "Using temporary; Using filesort" in coloumn of "Extra"  for "activity table" so I think it is creating temporary table with 28700 rows so actually it is running down. So please suggest me

Comment: Could you give me the execution times and the explains of both versions of the query? So I could take a look and tell you something.